# Build application for production

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

i found this tutorial that explains how to build your application for production.

My project structure is as follows;

```
ProjRoot
 --> app 
     *--> ext (this is the extjs folder)
     *--> model (model folder it contain the model files of the projec)
     *--> view
     *--> controller
     *--> store
     *--> resources
     *--> servercode
 --> app.html
 --> app.js
```

As the tutorial explained i navigated to ProjRoot from command prompt and typed the following code;

```
sencha create jsb -a http://localhost/ProjRoot/app.html -p app.jsb3
```

This created a file, which is 1kb app.jsb3

Then i executed the following code

```
sencha build -p app.jsb3 -d .
```

This produced 2 files.

1.) app-all.js 3KB

2.) all-classes.js 1KB

`app-all.js` contained code of the app.js file concatenated together, while `all-classes.js` didn't have any code inside it; i found the following code in it.

```
/*
Copyright(c) 2012 Company Name
*/
```

According to the tutorial, i should be able to add these 2 files in the server and make the application up. But unfortunately it's not working for me. Help ?

And also, i added the launching html file, where i refer the above 2 files in that.

Can someone please give me step by step instructions or tell me what i missed?

**UPDATE**

I get the following error when i type the command as described in your post. How can i resolve it ?

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\ProjRoot>sencha create jsb -a a
pp.html -p proj.jsb3 -v
Error thown from your application with message: TypeError: 'null' is not a const
ructor
```

Comment: I answered a different question about it [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12267322/1062992). It might help.

Comment: I will tr it out and get back to you.

Comment: I am getting an error. it says `TypeError: 'null' is not a const
ructor`. I have updated my post above with the exact error message i got. Help

Comment: Instead of using the `app.html` i used `localhost/projroot/app.html` in the `sencha create` statement and it generated the `jsb3` file. But, when i ran the 2nd command i got an empty file for `all-classes.js` as described in my post above. (the same error)

Comment: Verify the contents of the `jsb3` file. If it doesn't list any JavaScript files then the first command failed.
If it lists files correctly then verify that the paths are correct. As mentioned in Gernomos linked answer the paths are relative - so the execution directory of the second command matters.

Comment: Now, i get some of the file paths in the app-all.js. I got 1 model and 1 Store class added to the app-all.js file. the other files are not added. Help